# Method validateConfirm does not exist (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am following Dayle Rees' Laravel tutorial, trying to build a simple registration page.

If I submit the registration form with validation errors, the page reloads and shows me the validation errors. However, when I key in correct values and submit, I get the following error -

```
BadMethodCallException
Method [validateConfirm] does not exist.
```

This is my register.blade.php -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Registration form</h1>

{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/registration')) }}

    {{-- Username field. ------------------------}}
    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
    {{ Form::text('username') }}
    {{ $errors->first('username', '<span class="error">:message</span>') }}
<br/>
    {{-- Email address field. -------------------}}
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email address') }}
    {{ Form::email('email') }}
    {{ $errors->first('email', '<span class="error">:message</span>') }}
<br/>
    {{-- Password field. ------------------------}}
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
    {{ Form::password('password') }}
    {{ $errors->first('password', '<span class="error">:message</span>') }}
<br/>
    {{-- Password confirmation field. -----------}}
    {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Password confirmation') }}
    {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
<br/>
    {{-- Form submit button. --------------------}}
    {{ Form::submit('Register') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my routes.php [NOTE : The issue goes away if I remove the rule for password]

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('register');

});

Route::post('/registration', function()
{
    // Fetch all request data.
    $data = Input::all();

    // Build the validation constraint set.
    $rules = array(
        'username'   => 'required|min:3|max:32',
        'email'      => 'required|email',
        'password'   => 'required|confirm|min:3'
    );

    // Create a new validator instance.
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        // Normally we would do something with the data.
        return 'Data was saved.';
    }

    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Issue seems to be due to using `confirm` instead of `confirmed`. Resolved!

Comment: I am trying to do password reminder stuff and my error says Method [validatePassword] does not exist. I do not know where am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can include `->back()` or use

must be changed in your code , its required

```
   return Redirect::to('/')
                     ->back()
                     ->withErrors($validator);
```